# Git cherry-pick is disabled in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

We are cherry-picking commits on release branch and came across an issue where cherry-pick option is disabled for one specific commit.

Please see the image below

[image]

This problem is only with particular commit. We can see this option enabled for previous and next commits.

Please note that this commit is not a merge commit, it has changes in the files

[image]

One thing to note here, changes from NavigationRepository.cs file is available in final version of release branch but not from Templates.cs file.

Could someone please help me understand the issue and provide the solution?